# Resize all images to be of equal sizes

Tags: ios, image, tableview, cell, rounded-corners

I've done this before but it doesn't work for some reason. I'm trying to have round pictures in my tableview, and everything works fine except one thing :

The pictures aren't all of the same size, therefore the rounding doesn't work properly, and some photos are just ridiculous.

I'm using the code below.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.layer.frame.size.width/2;

//Getting the picture data of the current contact
NSData *pictureData  = [[[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]picture]data];
UIImage *picture;

//Setting the picture or a placeholder if none was found
if (pictureData == nil || pictureData.length < 15){
    picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
}else{
    picture = [UIImage imageWithData:pictureData];
}

cell.textLabel.text  = [[[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]compositeName];
cell.imageView.image = picture;

return cell;
```

What should I do to have round images at all times considering some of the imageviews (apparently...) are of different sizes.

Note that the tableview cells and images are all of equal height/width, they just get a cornerradius value that isn't half of their height apparently, but they're still not wider or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the UIImage to the the UIImageView I would recommend you to resize the image to the correct size (the size of the UIImageView).

This way the image will be rounded and the performance when scrolling will be better.

In order to resize the image you can use the following method:

```
- (UIImage*) scaleImage:(UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGSize scaledSize = newSize;
    float scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if( image.size.width > image.size.height ) {
        scaleFactor = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    else {
        scaleFactor = image.size.height / image.size.width;
        scaledSize.height = newSize.height;
        scaledSize.width = newSize.width / scaleFactor;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( scaledSize, NO, 0.0 );
    CGRect scaledImageRect = CGRectMake( 0.0, 0.0, scaledSize.width, scaledSize.height );
    [image drawInRect:scaledImageRect];
    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return scaledImage;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [self scaleImage:picture toSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
```